# createobject permissions denied issue

Tags: permissions, asp-classic

I have the dreaded permission denied issue when trying to create an object using the following code in asp.  Not sure how to identify what user needs more permissions in iis 6?  Is it the network service/ iusr/ iwam user?

```
Set objWorkflow = Server.CreateObject("xxx")
```

any ideas appreciated

many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are creating an object of any .dll then give full access right.

Comment: you mean 'everyone' full control ??